# Correct? "I have three new books, two bought from Amazon, and another one given by my sister"

Tags: grammar

"I have three new books, two bought from Amazon, and another one given by my sister".

I was writing this sentence, but is not sure if it is correct grammarly. Is there a better way to say it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: What is your reason for doubting its grammaticality?

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatical, although it reads awkwardly because the phrases are not parallel. To make it less awkward but less descriptive, you could say "two from Amazon, and one from my sister".

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

> I have three new books: two bought on Amazon, and *one* given by my sister.

Or

> I have three new books. Two were bought on Amazon, and one was given by my sister.

Or, more formally:

> I have three new books, two of which were bought on Amazon, and one [was] given by my sister.

Comment: *Why* should one write these things rather than the sentence in the question?

Comment: @Glyph OP's sentence is grammatical. It's just that "Two bought on Amazon, and another one..." sounds a bit jarring to my ear.

Comment: +1, because I think this is what OP intends to say. The original statement can be read as about 6 books (3 new; 3 old): "I have three new books, two bought [used] from Amazon, and another one given by my sister [hand-me-down]". These sentences remove that ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

*I have three new books, two bought from Amazon, and another one given by my sister.*

I have three new books, two from Amazon, and another gifted by my sister.

Mentioning 'purchasing' from Amazon is superfluous

Comment: "gifted by"? Unusual to say the least.